# ant support for java 9 addmods option

Tags: java, ant, java-9

I am trying to compile my java project with Java 9.
I am using the java.xml.bind package so I need to use the -addmods option
for compiling.  Ant 1.9.7 does not seem to support this new feature.
Does ant support -addmods option for Java 9 compiler?

Answer (score 6):

There is no explicit support in any released version of Ant at this point in time. But you should be able to use `<jvmarg>` for that

```
<java ....>
    <jvmarg value="--add-modules"/>
    <jvmarg value="module.name.to.add"/>
    <jvmarg ..../>
</java>
```

If you are asking about `<javac>` rather than `<java>`, `<compilerarg>` can be used instead.

There are quite a few ways that Java 9 manages to break Ant - and 1.9.8 and 1.10.x will contain a lot of fixes for it (there will be new releases soon once the last known issues have been ironed out). Right now there is no explicit support for `--add-modules`, though, only for `modulepath` and `upgrademodulepath` which have been added in Ant 1.9.7.

***IMHO - Would be a good enhancement request though.***

Comment: Note that `-addmods` was renamed to `--add-modules` in recent Java 9 early access builds

Comment: Also note that the use of `jvmarg` also requires the use of `fork="true"` in the `java` task (at least as of ant 1.10.13.  This took me a *very* long time to discover.

Answer (score -1):

Use at least Ant 1.10.1 and do the following in build.xml:

```
<condition property="java9">
  <equals arg1="${ant.java.version}" arg2="9"/>
</condition>

<java classname="....." fork="true">
  <classpath>
    <pathelement location="...."/>
  </classpath>
  <jvmarg value="--add-modules" if:set="java9" />
  <jvmarg value="java.xml.bind" if:set="java9" />
  ...
</java>
```