# Adding long JVM options to ant launch command

Tags: ant, java-9

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39275646/ant-support-for-java-9-addmods-option), I am looking for a way to supply long options (i.e. `--long-option myVal`) to the JVM used by ant.  However, my question is different because I want to specify these JVM options to the ant process itself, not some sub-process that ant creates (e.g. `<java>`).

Specifically, I need to specify `--add-modules java.se.ee` so that the ant tasks run by my build scripting have access to the JAXB classes.

What I have tried so far:

```
ant -f build.xml --add-modules java.se.ee
ant -f build.xml --add-modules=java.se.ee
ant -f build.xml -Dadd-modules=java.se.ee
ant -f build.xml -D--add-modules=java.se.ee
ant -f build.xml -propertyfile java9.properties
```

For the `-propertyfile` option I have tried having the contents of `java9.properties` as:

```
--add-modules java.se.ee
```

and also with the key and value on separate lines:

```
--add-modules
java.se.ee
```

Answer (score 4):

Finally found the answer in [the ant-users mailing list](http://ant.1045680.n5.nabble.com/How-to-increase-memory-used-by-JVM-in-Ant-td1355370.html).

You can specify `ANT_OPTS` as an environment variable and it will apply those options to the JVM (commonly used for increasing max heap size).

In my case the solution was doing:

```
export ANT_OPTS="--add-modules java.se.ee"
```

Comment: Unfortunately I could not succeed with Windows Env. 

I used 

`SET  ANT_OPTS="--add-modules java.se.ee"`

Answer (score 2):

You should find that `--add-modules=java.se.ee` works too.

Comment: As of what version? I am on 1.9.6 and it says unrecognized option for my version if I pass it in directly as an option to the ant command.